# Document, File Size Are Wrong Downloaded From iCloud Using NSFileManager

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I download files in my app from iCloud into a specific directory, and get the size of each downloaded files. I use [`NADocumentPicker`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/NADocumentPicker) for getting the documents from iCloud, and `NSFileManager` to get the size.

Files are downloaded *properly*. However, the size of *some* files downloaded are shown wrong within my app and as follows: `File Size: 272`. File sizes are shown in bytes. I use below code to get the file size.

```
var fileSize : UInt64 = 0

do {

   let attr : NSDictionary? = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePathURLString)

   if let _attr = attr {
      fileSize = _attr.fileSize();
      print("File Size: \(fileSize)")

      totalFileSize += fileSize

   }
} catch {
      print("Error: \(error)")
  }
```

I need to get correct file sizes, always. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this issue.